# Hugo not rendering the summary from the front matter

Tags: hugo

According to the [Hugo content summary guide](https://gohugo.io/content-management/summaries/), I can define a summary in 3 ways (listed in order of highest preference):

1. Use the `<!--more-->` tag to tell how much of the article Hugo should use as the summary
2. Use the `summary` variable in the front matter in order to use a custom summary
3. Let Hugo by default use the first 70 words of the article

First and foremost, here is the template I have for individual pages:

```
{{ partial "header" . }}
{{ partial "nav" . }}
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="subtitle tags is-6 is-pulled-right">
      {{ if .Params.tags }}
        {{ partial "tags" .Params.tags }}
      {{ end }}
    </div>
    {{if not .Date.IsZero }}
      <h2 class="subtitle is-6">{{ .Date.Format "January 2, 2006" }}</h2>
    {{ end }}
    <h1 class="title">{{ .Title }}</h1>
    {{ if .Site.Params.Info.related }}
      <div class="related">{{ partial "related" . }}</div>
    {{ end }}
    <div class="content">
      <h1 id="summary">Summary</h1>
      {{ .Summary }}
      <h1 id="toc">Table of Contents</h1>
      {{ .TableOfContents }}
      {{ .Content }}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{{ partial "footer" . }}
```

Here is a sample article I made:

```
---
title: "Test"
date: 2019-11-23T19:51:44-06:00
draft: true
summary: "This is a simple placeholder summary defined in the front matter"
---

This is a simple placeholder written in the article

# Section 1

Hello world!
```

The `title` and `date` render just fine, however, the `summary` is ignored and the words from the article as used as the summary:

[image]

I then used the `<!--more-->` tag like so:

```
---
title: "Test"
date: 2019-11-23T19:51:44-06:00
draft: true
summary: "This is a simple placeholder summary defined in the front matter"
---

This is a simple placeholder written in the article

<!--more-->

# Section 1

Hello world!
```

It worked like a charm...

[image]

So methods 1 and 3 for content summaries work, but method 2 does not. Is there a reason why I can't get the `summary` front matter to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was introduce in [Hugo 0.55.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.55.0) via [issue #5800](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/5800).

**Upgrade to Hugo 0.55.0 or above** to solve the issue

Comment: What versions of Hugo had this bug?

Comment: @jtooker Not sure, but Hugo 0.62.2 is what I use now. It might've been 0.(50-something).

Comment: I appear to be having this problem with v0.54.0/extended linux/arm BuildDate: 2019-06-04T19:16:36Z